# Requested Bean function generating error

Tags: java, spring

I've developed a Spring Application which overrides `Setter Injection` over `Constructor Injection`, 
but the getter function is generating error.

```
public class Book {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Book(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Spring.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="bookBean" class="com.abc.xyz.Book">
        <property name="name" value="ABCD"></property>
        <constructor-arg value="EFGH"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

ClientApp.java:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class ClientApp {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
    Book book = (Book) context.getBean("bookBean");
    book.getName();
}
```

Comment: what is the error message ? Why are you using <constructor-arg value="EFGH"></constructor-arg> when your purpose is to invoke your setter /?

Comment: @Georgesvanhoutte - The error message is ------Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token "getName", Identifier expected after 
  this token
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete MethodDeclaration ---- and I'm trying to override setterInjection over Constructor Injection thats why i use <constructor-arg> tag. I'm getting the error in ClientApp.java file at the line book.getName();

Comment: try using @Autowired annotation